# Eclipse: does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 4.17.0 on Mac OSX 11.0, JVM 8 gives an alert when I try to run it:

"The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/.../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol"

The application does not start.

Comment: Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) requires at least Java 11 to run.